# Google Maps not loading with variable value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps, replace

I am trying to load Google Maps through ajax but maps won't show if I pass my variable i.e. `location_data` but If i manually put the same data in markers array it display the map along with markers accordingly. Secondly I want to reload map through ajax with new markers but stuck into the same problem. I tried all the possible solutions but nothing works for me, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is my HTML Code to display Array from JSON and map

```
<div id="print_json">JSON Data Here</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

This is return from my PHP file

```
["['test 1', 25.1212, 55.1535, 5]","['test 2', 25.2084, 55.2719, 6]","['test 3', 25.2285, 55.3273, 7]"]
```

This is my JavaScript

```
function initMap(location_data) {
    var map;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the web page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(50);

    // Multiple markers location, latitude, and longitude
    alert(location_data);
    //var markers = location_data;
    var markers = [
        ['test 1', 25.1212, 55.1535, 5],
        ['test 2', 25.2084, 55.2719, 6],
        ['test 3', 25.2285, 55.3273, 7]
    ];

    // Info window content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<h3>Brooklyn Museum</h3>' +
            '<p>The Brooklyn Museum is an art museum located in the New York City borough of Brooklyn.</p>' + '</div>'
        ],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<h3>Brooklyn Public Library</h3>' +
            '<p>The Brooklyn Public Library (BPL) is the public library system of the borough of Brooklyn, in New York City.</p>' +
            '</div>'
        ],
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
            '<h3>Prospect Park Zoo</h3>' +
            '<p>The Prospect Park Zoo is a 12-acre (4.9 ha) zoo located off Flatbush Avenue on the eastern side of Prospect Park, Brooklyn, New York City.</p>' +
            '</div>'
        ]
    ];

    // Add multiple markers to map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        marker, i;

    // Place each marker on the map  
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });

        // Add info window to marker    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Center the map to fit all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Set zoom level
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(5);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

}


// Sets the map on all markers in the array.

// Load initialize function
//google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

$(document).ready(function() {
    var location_data;
    $("#mapped").on("change", function() {
        var dataname = $(".selectpicker option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "findforwork.php",
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            //dataType: "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            data: "searchid=" + dataname,
            success: function(response) {
                //alert('Success' + response);
                $("#print_json").html(response.replace(/\"/g, ""));
                console.log(JSON.parse(response));
                var location_data = response.replace(/\"/g, "");
                var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapDiv, "load", initMap(location_data));
            }
        }); //End Of Ajax
    }); //End of mapped
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON.parse()` after `.replace()`

```
var response= '["[\'test 1\', 25.1212, 55.1535, 5]","[\'test 2\', 25.2084, 55.2719, 6]","[\'test 3\', 25.2285, 55.3273, 7]"]';
var location_data = JSON.parse(response.replace(/\"/g, "").replace(/\'/g, "\""));
console.log(location_data);
```

Output

```
0: Array(4) [ "test 1", 25.1212, 55.1535, … ]
1: Array(4) [ "test 2", 25.2084, 55.2719, … ]
2: Array(4) [ "test 3", 25.2285, 55.3273, … ]
```

Comment: I already placed a check to remove double quotes `var location_data = response.replace(/\"/g, "");` please see success message

Comment: I thought the php response was the `console.log(JSON.parse(response));` located after the `response.replace(/\"/g, "");`

Comment: I got this VM658:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2

Comment: This is even more worst. The good answer is use the Google Translate API, however, he search a solution to his code, not your opinion on his job... You have zero knowledge about if he can or not altering the PHP side...

Comment: @JonathanGagne Perfect Solution thank your very much

Comment: @JonathanGagne you saved my day God Bless you :) and I already did it

Comment: Anytime! It was my pleasure!